# Calling a function in C without parentheses that works, how?

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting, structure

I know there are questions asking if you can call a function without parentheses and the answer to that is no but in my code that works and I'd like to know why.

```
typedef struct{
    //some variables
} REG;

long foo(){
    //some code
    return 23; //i.e 23, it could be any positive integer
}

REG * foo1(REG **ptr){
    //some code

    *ptr = calloc( (int) foo , sizeof(REG)); //foo without ()

    //more code
    fread(*ptr,sizeof(REG), foo(), fp); 

    return *ptr;

}
```

I'm compiling in xcode, it gives no error/warning.

Comment: What level of warnings have you requested? You should be receiving warnings about *casting a pointer to an integer of different size*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I used xcode so I don't know how to choose the level of warnings, and no it did not give any warning

Comment: 1st result from search `xcode enable warnings` [Xcode Warnings: Can You Turn Them Up to Eleven?](https://qualitycoding.org/xcode-warnings/) or [Warnings in Xcode](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/08/17/warnings-in-xcode) (2nd result)

Comment: Define "allocates the memory correctly", specifically what you mean by "correct" and how you arrive at that conclusion. You are most assuredly not calling 'foo'.

Comment: @DaveNewton actually it doesnt allocate it correctly as I wanted it, I'm gonna edit the question. Thanks for all the help, TimJohns is right.

Comment: Trying to write a function call without using parentheses is like trying to write the word "the" without using the letter 'e'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this looks like it is taking the address of the `foo` function, casting it to an `int`, and using that `int` as the first argument (`num`) to `calloc`.  This will most likely allocate a large amount of memory, rather than just enough for 23 elements that you think it's allocating, which explains why the `fread` does not cause any errors.

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. There is nothing magic -- I sure hope `sizeof(REG)` is really small...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes sizeof(REG) is small, about 40B. In xcode I can see memory usage and foo without () took 100x more memory than with ().